# Golang cast to a custom type fails if I wrap my object

Tags: go, casting

In my app I use `validator.v9` to validate my model. After validation I can cast the `error` interface and it's successes, I see 'OK' on the console

```
err := v.ModelValidator.Struct(model)

if _, ok := err.(validator.ValidationErrors); ok {
    fmt.Println("ValidateModel: OK")
} else{
    fmt.Println("ValidateModel: FALSE")
}
```

I need to wrap this object to another one for future processing

```
type errValidation struct {
    error
}

func ValidationError(err error) error {
    return errValidation{err}
}
```

But if I try to cast this wrapped object back to `validator.ValidationErrors` in the same function just below the cast from a first case above it fails

```
e := ValidationError(err)
if _, ok := e.(validator.ValidationErrors); ok {
    fmt.Println("ValidationError: OK")
} else{
    fmt.Println("ValidationError: FALSE")
}
```

I see in the console

```
ValidateModel: OK
ValidationError: FALSE
```

How can I make this cast work from wrapped object?

`ValidationErrors` from `"gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9"` looks like this

```
type ValidationErrors []FieldError
func (ve ValidationErrors) Error() string {
     //.....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `errValidation` type and the `validator.ValidationErrors` type are completely different, distinct types. If an interface value holds a value of concrete type `errValidation`, you can't type assert another concrete type from it, only `errValidation`.

So this will work:

```
e := ValidationError(errors.New("some err"))
if _, ok := e.(errValidation); ok {
    fmt.Println("ValidationError: OK")
} else {
    fmt.Println("ValidationError: FALSE")
}
```

And output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yC4VBtyevNw)):

```
ValidationError: OK
```